# Cannot resolve R android studio 1.2.1.1

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, r.java-file

I have just created an android project in android studio 1.2.1.1 but it says cannot resolve R. I have not changed the manifest or the xml which are usually responsible for that problem.

Comment: Try to build or clean project. It always occurs after create new project because R is generating at build process not while creating project.

Comment: I am sorry i did not mentioned it but i have already done those

Comment: my log mostly says: No resource found that matches the given name:attr 'android...

Comment: There is an error in one of resource file. Paste it contents.

Comment: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/21Z7

Comment: In which line the error occurs?

Comment: in line 14, 20, 32. I think i am missing aidl and since there many availiable answers for that i'll try to solve the problem through them and accept your answer as right because of the interest you showed, therefore if you want post one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post the answer for anyone finding it useful, in the end i just had to update the sdk manager to 22.0.1 and change the gradle build tools version to the latest meaning the one i downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Try to build or clean project. It always occurs after create new project because R is generating at build process not while creating project.

Answer (score 0):

Its also happens when you dont have necessary support files.. 
Check the error log, it should be showing some kind of error that will help you to resolve the problem..

Answer (score -1):

Check if yours xmls are ok,you can have bugs there. 
Also try clean the project or build it again.Other solution can be change something in your code and build.
R.java is a file that regenerate, so you can close Android Studio, delete R.java and open it again.